# Google script for google sheets - Range copy paste special 'add'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

i'm really newbie at scripting, i used to do my work with microsoft office that have a special paste "add" feature and now for google sheet i can't really find it.

I will have a source range of C2:C102 and destination at same sheet D2:D102 i want the script (that i can run manually weekly) to copy all the range from source and sum it with the already existing data at D2:D102 (only values).

Here is a small example - [Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4koeU.png) [after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4k8kI.png)

I tried to use this code but ofc it just replaces the values.

```
function copyCells(){
   var thisSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var SourceSheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
  var SourceRange = thisSpreadsheet.getRange("C2:C102");

  var destinationSheet = thisSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
  var destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("D2:D102");

   SourceRange.copyTo(destinationRange, {contentsOnly: true}); 
}
```

Any help will be really appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't tested the code but try this.

- grab values with `getValues()`
- sum the values
- copy back values with `setValues()`

  ```
  function copyCells(){
     const spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     const SourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
     const SourceRange = spreadsheet.getRange("C2:C102");
     const SourceValues = SourceRange.getValues();

     const destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("test");
     const destinationRange = destinationSheet.getRange("D2:D102");
     const destinationValues = destinationRange.getValues();

     for (let i = 0; i < SourceValues.length; i++)
       destinationValues[i][0] = parseFloat(destinationValues[i][0]) + parseFloat(SourceValues[i][0])

     destinationRange.setValues(destinationValues);
  }
  ```

**REFERENCES**

[range.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)

[range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: Looks like its working, the only problem i have is when i add decimal number, for example if the C2 have 12,5 Value it will add only the 12